# How to set default mode headset in android

Tags: java, android, voip

I am working on a VoIP app, I get an issue when user unplugs headphone then device automatically switches to loud speaker but I want device to switch to normal speaker. Is there any way I can change it to normal speaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky stuff, esp multiple devices, different scenarios.
I have worked on a VoIP app that is how i know this. What you are facing is probably because the audio manager mode and-or stream is being handled manually after requesting focus. What you need to do is to transfer the control to the call stream so while your call is on,
connection and disconnection of headset, transfer to the phone earpiece etc is handled automatically by the o.s.

You could probably be doing all of this or a combination...

Use [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) {[.setMode(int mode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setMode(int))} - use [MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION), recommended for VoIP or [MODE_IN_CALL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#MODE_IN_CALL)

Also, check [STREAM_VOICE_CALL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_VOICE_CALL)

Are you usinng 
- [isSpeakerphoneOn()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isSpeakerphoneOn()) and [setSpeakerphoneOn(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setSpeakerphoneOn(boolean)) 
- [isBluetoothScoOn()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isBluetoothScoOn()), [setBluetoothScoOn(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setBluetoothScoOn(boolean)) ?

Will need to play around with all of those for device or headset model specific issues.

Useful stuff:

> Even if a SCO connection is established, the following restrictions
>   apply on audio output streams so that they can be routed to SCO
>   headset:
>
> - the stream type must be STREAM_VOICE_CALL
> - the format must be mono
> - the sampling must be 16kHz or 8kHz

Comment: Thank for your helps, but i have a problem it will be stay in loud speaker about 1.5s before switch to normal speaker

Comment: Ok..what audio mode is your app in while on call?

Comment: I think MODE_IN_CALL because this app using Cordova make a call in webview through crosswalk so i don't know why delay when switch to normal speaker

Comment: is this behavior device/o.s. specific or happens with your app only on multiple devices/o.s.

Comment: It just happen in Android OS

Answer (score 1):

To turn on earpiece programmatically try this:

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

private void useEarpiece() {
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
}
```

Check your permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

To catch event:

```
private class HeadSetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            switch (state) {
            case 0:
                // Headset unplugged
                break;
            case 1:
                // Headset plugged in
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but when i switch to normal speaker it will be stay in loud speaker about 1.5s before switch to normal speaker

Comment: Thank for this bro!

Comment: Not working on webView